# Autodesk Forge: Rhino .3dm importing with layer materials instead of the true materials

Tags: autodesk-forge

Hi I'm trying to convert Rhino .3dm models using forge but it imports with the layer color instead of the material color. If I export to .skp from Rhino, and then import the skp into Forge, I see the true material colors. I'm wondering if there's a way to access these material colors just by importing 3dm?

Comment: I am checking with relevant engineer team

Comment: Sorry, it might be some delay to get the response from our engineer team due to the winter break. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Happy New Year! Sorry for the late response! I got the comments from our engineer team: There is a setting “display mode” in Rhino to indicate whether to display material color or normal color. Currently in Rhino to the format of Forge Viewer (SVF) workflow, it doesn’t support material color. While probably Could you share a demo Rhino file in case we missed some other scenarios ? thank you.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Thank you for looking into this! In Revit I've noticed that saving the model in the rendered mode vs the shaded mode will result in different material appearances when the file is loaded into Forge. I'm starting to realize how this might not be feasible for the 3dm format since Rhino models have multiple viewports, each of which can have different appearances. It would be useful to our project if the different material properties from 3dm files (shaded and rendered) were available in the property list via model.getProperties(dbId, result), especially color and material name.

Comment: sorry I have not an answer on this. I am not familiar with Rhino. Please bear with me checking with engineer team